# How to handle item select in AngularJS Autocomplete

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete, angularjs-material

I am very new to AngularJS..

I managed to implement Autocomplete control by using example

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/autocomplete

Unfortunately it is only part of my control. And now I have tried everything but I can't get how to handle the event when an item get selected.

I am trying to implement multiple selects one depending on selected value of another.

Thanks!

Comment: if you want to trigger a function you can use ng-click. but is your problem this?

Comment: No ng-click does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `md-selected-item-change` attribute

> md-selected-item-change   expression   An expression to be run each time
>   a new item is selected

eg:

```
<md-autocomplete
          ...
          md-selected-item-change="selectedItemChange(item)">
</md-autocomplete>
```

js:

```
$scope.selectedItemChange = function(item) {
  $log.info('Item changed to ' + JSON.stringify(item));
}
```

Comment: That works with slight adjustment to the example context..                       md-selected-item-change="ctrl.selectedItemChange(item)"